# Exceptions throwing exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

When playing around with exceptions in C++, I noticed a curious behaviour that I was hoping someone here could explain. Look at the code below:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    Foo()
    {
        throw 0;
    }
};

class RandomException
{
public:

    Foo f;
};

void bar()
{
    throw RandomException();
}

// Case #1
int main()
{
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

In the case above, I have an unhandled exception. Now if I change the body of the `main` function to:

```
// Case #2
int main()
{
    try
    {
        bar();
    }
    catch (int)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm swallowing the exception. There are no unhandled exceptions, and the code runs fine. And if I change the code to:

```
// Case #3
int main()
{
    try
    {
        bar();
    }
    catch (RandomException&)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I have an unhandled exception again.

I want to know why in case Case #2 I have no unhandled exceptions, and in Case #3 I do, even though in both cases I'm throwing 2 exceptions, one `int` and one of type `RandomException`.

How does C++ handle things when an exception is thrown while throwing an exception?

Comment: why would you throw an exception _inside_ of a custom exception class? That's insane. The constructor of RandomException calls the constructor of Foo which throws and you only catch that exception in case 2, not case 3.

Comment: You end up in [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Crashception.aspx). 8v)

Comment: @stefan For science, of course. Why else?

Comment: @stefan Any exception type that uses e.g. `std::string` exposes itself to throwing `std::bad_alloc` or some such at construction time. `std::runtime_error` would be an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, the construction of the `RandomException` object fails with an exception, so `throw RandomException()` is never completed and an `int` (0) is thrown (in the process of constructing `RandomException`).

If you have a handler for that (as in case #2), control will be transferred to that handler. If not (as in case #3), `std::terminate()` will be invoked.

Comment: So because the construction of `RandomException` is never "completed", it never gets thrown?

Comment: @Zeenobit: Indeed, that's what is happening.